# vba - importing data from other workbook without losing date format

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following code to import data from one (closed) workbook (test.xlsx) into another (open) workbook:

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim FilePath    As String
Dim StartRow    As Integer
Dim rep         As Integer
Dim ws          As Worksheet
Dim SourceWb    As Workbook
Dim LastRow     As Range

FilePath = "C:\Users\koteletje\Documents\test.xlsx"
StartRow = 1

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
Set SourceWb = Workbooks.Open(FilePath, True, True)
Set LastRow = SourceWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=SourceWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1), _
LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

For rep = StartRow To LastRow.Row
    ws.Range("A" & rep & ":II" & rep).Formula = _
    SourceWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & rep & ":II" & rep).Formula
Next rep
End Sub
```

Some of the columns (not known in advance which) contain dates. When copying the data (see loop at the end of the code), I do not manage to keep the dates in the original format; e.g. '13/11/2009  10:09:44' becomes '40130.4234259259'. **Is there an easy way to keep the original formatting?**

I also actually have a second question related to this code. Instead of using the columns letter references 'II' in the loop, I wanted to use the number of the last column holding data introduced ('II' is just a column letter considered to be high enough to never run into trouble)

```
Set LastColumn = SourceWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=SourceWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1), _
LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
```

And updated the loop as follows:

```
For rep = StartRow To LastRow.Row
    Worksheets(ws.Name).Range(Cells(rep, 1), Cells(rep, LastColumn.Column)).Formula = _
    SourceWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(rep, 1), Cells(rep, LastColumn.Column)).Formula
Next rep
```

Unfortunately, this yields the error: Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range.

I don't understand why it is out of range. **Why do I get this error?** Has it something to do with using Cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write the worksheet for the cells as well:

```
ws.Range(ws.Cells(rep, 1), ws.Cells(rep, LastColumn.Column)).Formula = _
SourceWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(SourceWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(rep, 1), SourceWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(rep, LastColumn.Column)).Formula
```

You can also get a lighter code using the `With` and omitting the worksheet but keeping the dot:

```
With SourceWb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(rep, 1), ws.Cells(rep, LastColumn.Column)).Value = _
    .Range(.Cells(rep, 1), .Cells(rep, LastColumn.Column)).Value
End With
```

Comment: I edited my answer and replaced `.Formula` by `.Value` Does it fix your formatting problem?